# Beautiful soup - Extract value from span class

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have managed to extract the below text from a webpage using beautiful soup. I would like to extract the value 5.3% from the span class.

```
<h2>
<span class="group_name">All Files</span>
(<span class="cover"><span class="red">5.3%</span></span>
 covered at
 <span class="cover_strength">
 <span class="green"> 545 </span>
</span> hits/line)
</h2>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Value `5.3%` is in span tag with class attribute 'red'.

```
html='''
<h2>
<span class="group_name">All Files</span>
(<span class="cover"><span class="red">5.3%</span></span>
 covered at
 <span class="cover_strength">
 <span class="green"> 545 </span>
</span> hits/line)
</h2>
'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#print(soup.prettify())
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    
result = soup.find("span", {"class": "red"})
print(result.text)
```

**Output:**

```
5.3%
```